# Can I change a field from a formula to a text with Force.com IDE?

Tags: formula-field, force.com-ide

I've been asked to change a bunch of fields to Text type fields without changing the API name. I know this is possible by deleting the field in production and creating a new one, however this poses a major issue since the references to this field are manifold.

I'd like to be able to do this from within the IDE since I know I've access to the metadata, but I foresee Salesforce not liking this kind of operation. Is this possible, and what considerations do I need to make?

I don't particularly care if the data gets deleted, I'm reincorporating these formulas into an Apex class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [help](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=notes_on_changing_custom_field_types.htm&language=en) says:

> Formula fields are special read-only fields that cannot be converted
>   to any other data type. Likewise, you cannot convert any other field
>   type into a formula field.

So for this change you are out of luck, but non-destructive changes (such as making text fields longer or adding new fields) do work fine in my experience when done from the IDE's metadata.

Answer (score 3):

No. When you edit most fields, you will see a <kbd>Change Field Type</kbd> button. When you edit a formula field, this button does not appear.